# return the first n letters of a column

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I know that MySQL can choose queries with certain length.

Can MySQL output only the first 10 letters from the word?

Form Example

```
mysql_query(SELECT LEFT(col,10),some2,some3 FROM someTable);
```

In the `col` I have for example

```
'TextForExampleLongerThanTen'
'Text' 
'SHORTER'
'LONGERAGAINTHANTEN'
```

I want these all to be output but, only their first 10 symbols

Comment: You may be looking for this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use "LEFT()", e.g.

```
SELECT LEFT(col, 10) FROM table;
```

Comment: This just output the columns that are to 10 simbols, i want to output all of the queryies in the column but to output only the first 10 simbols of each one of it .

Comment: @waraza, do you mean you want the first 10 **different** letters (characters) from the field?

Comment: no, just i want when outputing a query- the query characters to be no more than 10. Just to get the first 10 query characters and output them.

Comment: So, qbert220's answer is correct. It shows the first 10 characters of column `col` .

Comment: @waraza if this is not what you are after, edit the question with some rows of data and the expected output

Comment: mysql_query(SELECT LEFT(col,10),some2,some3 FROM someTable);
In the col i have for example

TextForExampleLongerThanTen
Text
SHORTER
LONGERAGAINTHANTEN
I want theese all to be outputed but, only their first 10 simbols

Comment: I guess (now) that you mean the first 10 characters from all columns of the table. So, somthing like this would work:

`SELECT
    LEFT(some1, 10) 
  , LEFT(some2, 10)
  , LEFT(some3, 10)
  FROM table;`